# Procedure insert into another table using cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm creating a procedure, using cursor, which checks in different tables if the current quantity of 5 products are below their minimum quantity. If the current quantity is below I create a PURCHASE ORDER (table). I'm having difficulty capturing the information from the different tables in the course to create the PURCHASE ORDER. The path between the tables is: stock_product (id_product) -> product (lot_number) -> item_product (id_purchase) -> purchase_order

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchase_order`(
    `id_purchase` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `total_consolidated` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    `was_canceled` SET('Y','N'),
    `branch_number` INT(14) NOT NULL,
    `date_accomplished` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id_purchase`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`branch_number`)
    REFERENCES `branch` (`branch_number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_product`(
    `lot_number` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_purchase` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `quantity_requested` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`lot_number`),
   FOREIGN KEY(`id_purchase`)
   REFERENCES `purchase_order` (`id_purchase`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product`(
    `id_product`INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `minimum_quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    `lot_number` INT(11) NOT NULL,     
    PRIMARY KEY(`id_product`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`lot_number`)
    REFERENCES `item_product` (`lot_number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)   
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_product`(
    `id_stock_product`INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    `current_quantity`INT(11) NOT NULL,   
    `id_product`INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY(`id_stock_product`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`id_product`)
    REFERENCES `product` (`id_product`)    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_generate_purchase_order()
BEGIN
    DECLARE countN INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE minimumQuantity INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentQuantity INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT  P.minimum_quantity, SP.current_quantity  from produc P inner join stock_product as SP
on P.id_product = SP.id_product;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;  
    OPEN curs;    
    FETCH curs INTO minimumQuantity, currentQuantity;
    WHILE countN != 5
        FETCH curs INTO minimumQuantity, currentQuantity;
        IF currentQuantity <= minimumQuantity
        THEN /*create the purchase order*/;
        END IF;
        set countN = countN + 1;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE curs;
    
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with a cursor? Just write a query that returns the rows, and use `INSERT INTO purchase_order (columns...) SELECT columns... FROM product INNER JOIN stock_product ...`

Comment: You can use `WHERE minumumQuantity < currentQuantity` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: Oh, it's not so simple, because you have to create the PO first, then use `id_purchase` in the `id_product` that you're inserting.

Comment: Should `currentQuantity <= minimumQuantity` be `<` instead of `<=`? If the current quantity is equal to the minimum, you don't need to order any more.

Comment: What goes into the purchase_order columns?

Comment: I don't understand your schema. How can you have rows in `item_product` before you create the `purchase_order`? But that seems to be required, because `product` has a foreign key to `item_product`.

Comment: You need an `order_items` table that contains the items being purchased on a particular PO.

Comment: @Barmar I first created the purchase_order table

Comment: I'm talking about the foreign key relationships. If you have products that don't need purchases, the FK requires a purchase_order row.